# How to handle elements with WebDriver that are dynamically generated by JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I am a junior when it comes to automation with Java and WebDriver, and I am stuck in the following problem:

1. Search a customer
2. Change customer type from a drop-down
3. Press Save button.

Result:
A message appears (generated by a JS/Jquery) inside a notification div container (see below code)
that can be "Saving your changes", either "Success" or "Failed", depending on the customer I am trying to change.

```
 <div id="notifications">
            <ul id="noty_inline_layout_container" class="" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; list-style-type: none; z-index: 9999999;">
                <li style="overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 234, 168) url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS")  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 194, 55); cursor: pointer; height: 1px;">
                    <div id="noty_545247324387577860" class="noty_bar">
                          <div class="noty_message" style="font-size: 13px;">
                              <span class="noty_text">Saving your changes...</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                <li style="overflow: hidden; background: lightgreen url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB=="); border: 1px solid rgb(80, 194, 78); cursor: pointer; height: 1px;">
                    <div id="noty_851025645275431000" class="noty_bar">
                        <div class="noty_message" style="font-size: 13px; ">
                            <span class="noty_text">Success</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Message fades away after a while, notification div container has no child elements anymore and looks like this:

```
<div id="notifications"></div>
```

How can I extract the text ("Saving your changes", or "Success") of the JS message since this appears and fades away?

Comment: Please provide an example and include necessary codes

Comment: Start by reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the code and the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can just fetch the text using `WebElement#getText()`.

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.noty_text")).getText();
```

or, if you'd like more specificity:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#notifications  span.noty_text")).getText();
```

then do what you will with `text`

Make sure that you execute this "before" the message fades away otherwise you might get a StaleReferenceException.